# How to Display Visual Scene List Studio Xamarin IOS Storyboard?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I've started developing an IOS app with Xamarin. This is a screen of a scenelist in the storyboard in Xamarin studio. Can I also display this in Visualstudio 2015?:

[image]

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent in Visual Studio is the **WPF Tree Visualizer**.

You can read more about how to use this here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/01/29/using-the-wpf-tree-visualizer/